# handling css with Jawr

Tags: css, jawr

my scenario:

- large amount of JSP (about 3000)
- not too much css files (about 100)

Today I have a lot of bundles that includes a couple of css files, as needed.
Then the jsp includes: or the bundles or the css files.

#### Is Jawr the best choice for me?

#### How do you handle you css files?

Answer (score 4):

You can either bundle your web resources on the runtime (using a servlet/filter) or buildtime (maven plugin or ant). There are several tools which help you to do that. I will just list some of them:

1. [Jawr](https://jawr.java.net/)
2. [JSO](http://js-optimizer.sourceforge.net/2.2.3/)
3. [wro4j](http://alexo.github.com/wro4j)

Jawr can be your best choice as long as it does exactly what you need.

Disclaimer: I'm a member of one of these project, however this answer is not biased.